# Mutt bash script sends email fine from command line but not from motioneye notification hook

Tags: bash, freebsd, mutt, ssmtp

So I'm about ready to pull my hair out on this one. I am running ssmtp and mutt on a freeBSD jail. I have a bash script called notify that contains the following line.

```
mutt -s "$subject" "$email" -a "$attachment" < "$logfile3"
```

When I run

> bash notify.sh

The email will send just fine, but if I run that exact same command from inside motioneye I receive an extremely non-descript error from mutt [image]

> Could not send the message

I have tried using a daemon but that hasn't had any effect. I wish the mutt error message was more descriptive.

Comment: It could be your PATH variable.  In notify.sh, near the top, add the debug line: `echo "$PATH" > /tmp/notify.debug.$$`.  Then run notify.sh manually, and run it again under motioneye.  Compare the two /tmp/notify.debug.* files and see if they have the same path.

Comment: Outside:
`/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/root/bin`

Inside:
(I'll update this when I get home and can trigger the camera)

Comment: Inside: `/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/root/bin` The paths are identical so that's not it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My script did not have access to the "sent" mailbox and therefore mutt was failing to send. `-e "set copy=no"` added to the mutt call corrected the issue.

For a better walkthrough: https://gitlab.com/muttmua/mutt/issues/119

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `bash` installed (it isn't by default on FreeBSD) and try using absolute path to it (`/usr/local/bin/bash`).

Comment: Bash is installed and running on both commandine and the script itself. All other aspects of notify.sh function just fine.